Google Appsheet Display Image base on Form field selection
I am creating a Stock Take form, due to one Description (SKU) will have multiple colours, so it will be easier to display the items picture base on the Description and Colour selected.
However, refer to image below, I am having issue displaying the right image in the form base on other field selection.
I tested my expression, it shows the right value at "Expression Result" but it is not displaying on the form.


IF(
ISNOTBLANK(
    ANY(
        SELECT(
            Flower Pictures[_ID],
            [File] = CONCATENATE([Description], "_", [Colour], ".png")
        )
    )
),
CONCATENATE(
    "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id=",
    ANY(
        SELECT(
            Flower Pictures[_ID],
            [File] = CONCATENATE([Description], "_", [Colour], ".png")
        )
    )
),
"https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id=1aIQVC6J6LQPhxUq9eYowBGlfldMmPPst")

I have try with other shorter expression, like "Lookup" or "Select". All doesn't work as expected. Example:
"https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id="& any(SELECT(
            Flower Pictures[_ID],
            [File] = CONCATENATE([Description], "_", [Colour], ".png")))

Need some guidance on this. Preferable way is that in this form user able to select picture directly instead of color after selecting "Barcode".
Thank you in advance.
REFERENCE

Table: Stock Take

Table: Flower Pictures

